# Detect if Webbrowser redirects

Tags: c#, javascript, redirect, browser

I am looking for a way a WebBrowser instance can detect if the currentpage is going to redirect.  Or, if an ad pops up when the page is initially loaded and then goes to the actual URL, I am looking for a way to detect that.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "Navigating" event of WebBrowser control and cancel the navigation if you want

Comment: So that would detect any navigation and not necessarily a redirect?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic Yes, So  what? Question is *I am looking for a way to detect that.* and this event can be used to detect it combined with your a few lines of code.