# How to distinguish between a user clicking a link and the page doing an automatic redirect in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, url, uiwebview

The question is almost the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050548/how-to-distinguish-between-a-user-clicking-a-link-and-the-page-doing-an-automati). The difference is that question is about C# app in Windows but I want to ask about Objective-C app in iOS (maybe their behaviour differs in this case).

In common I want to implement the following:

1) If a user actively navigates to another URL, I want to allow it.

2) If the page redirects "on its own" to another URL, I want to cancel it.

In both cases "another URL" is the same. How to solve this issue?

Comment: **If the page redirects "on its own" to another URL**... how this will occur? an example please.

Comment: I don't currently have an exact example. Something like the following link: https://openload.co/f/_oRbcKJuukU/%27%D0%90%27_%5B%D0%A1_Azazin_Kreet%5D_%23_1_%28%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B8%CC%86%29.mp4
   If you click the video then an ad page loads but then it redirects to a forbidden website. Or is it still user clicked link?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using UIWebView, you should set the delegate of the UIWebView to your ViewController, then in the ViewController, you should implement the following delegate of the UIWebView and return YES or NO to allow the URL to load or not:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([request.URL.absoluteString containsString:@"blah"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: URL links are **the same**

Comment: @lefteris can you please answer my question ... i m stuck